# insu. company finds that the ages of motorcyclists killed in crashes are normally distributed with a mean of 26.9 yrs &standard deviation of 8.4 yrs

Tags: normal-distribution

Just want to know if I solved it correctly 
A insurance company finds that the ages of motorcyclists killed in crashes are normally distributed with a mean of 26.9 yrs &standard deviation of 8.4 yrs

If we randomly selected one such motorcyclists find the probability that he or she was under 25 years of age ?

P(x<25)= normalcdf(25,1000,26.9,8.4)
= 0.589

If we randomly select one such motorcyclists, find the probability that he or she was over 35 years of age?

P(x>35)= normalcdf(35,1000,26.9,8.4)
= 0.167

Comment: Okay, so what are you asking? The first part seems to be wrong because 25 years old is less than the average; so the answer should be less than 50%.

Comment: The questions is in the descriptive part because it wouldn’t fit, above the answer. 
I just want to know if I solved it right

Comment: So I don't know what this notation with "normalcfd" means, but indeed I would calculate
$$
P(X<25) = \Phi \left( \frac{25 - 26.9}{8.4} \right) \approx 0.410~527
$$
and
$$
P(X>35) = 1- \Phi \left( \frac{35 - 26.9}{8.4} \right) \approx 0.167 451
$$

Comment: You put it into the calculator on the normalcdf that’s what it means and it calculates it . So is it the z score I’m solving in this one?

Comment: Come on, not every calculator in the world has that function. Next time, try to use notation that everyone would understand.

Comment: In a scientific /graphing calculator TI-84, ppl do use it commonly in college.